# Intersection Sphere - Plane

Tags: geometry, circles, plane-geometry, spheres

Which is the intersection of the sphere $S^2$ and the plane $x_a(\lambda , \mu)=(a, \lambda , \mu), \ a\in (0,1), \ \lambda , \mu\in \mathbb{R}$ ?

If the plane goes through the sphere the intersection is a circle, right? It is also possible that the intersection is a point. Otherwise there is no intersection.

So we have tocheck the distance of the plane from the center of the sphere, if it is less than the radius, equl or greater, right?

Howcan we do that in this case?

Comment: Can you precise what the plane $x_a(\lambda , \mu)=(a, \lambda , \mu)$ means? And yes, to look at the intersection of a plane and a sphere, you have to look at the distance from the plane to the center of the sphere.

Comment: Ithink that is the direction vector of the plane, but I am not sure. What do we get then in that case? @mathcounterexamples.net

Comment: So we have only a retriction for $a$. What do we get from that about the distance? @mathcounterexamples.net

Comment: I don't think that guessing the meaning of the question is appropriate. You should get the required details.

Comment: A question.... Could the intersection be also the line that passes through the points $(\pm a , 0 , 0)$ ? @mathcounterexamples.net

Comment: No, the intersection of a sphere and a plane is never a line. It's always either a circle, a point, or the empty set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that
$$
x_a(\lambda, \mu) = \big\{(a,\lambda,\mu) \in \mathbb R^3: \lambda \in \mathbb R, \mu \in \mathbb R \big\}
$$
In other words, $x_a(\lambda, \mu)$ is just a ridiculously complicated way to refer to the plane $x=a$. It's especially goofy since we're given a parametric equation for the plane, and the parameterization has no affect whatsoever on the intersection with the sphere.

Where this plane intersects the sphere
$S^2 = \big\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3:  x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1 \big\}$,
we have $a^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ and so $y^2 + z^2 = 1 - a^2$. So, the intersection is a circle lying on the plane $x=a$, with radius $\sqrt{1-a^2}$. The radius expression $\sqrt{1-a^2}$ makes sense because we're told that $0 < a < 1$.

If $a=1$, then the intersection circle degenerates into a point at $(1,0,0)$.

If $a >1$ or $a<-1$, there is no intersection.

Comment: Thank you!! :-)